# Identity Provider menu in Azure AD B2C not showing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

All,

[image: missing menu link in azure ad b2c]

I have been trying for hours to show to Identity Providers menu in Azure AD B2C to no avail as I need to add FB as Identity Provider. May I know if there is a role I need to assign myself. I have assigned all roles to myself including the global administrator role.

Comment: Can you click on **Overview** and provide a screenshot?

Comment: updated with screenshot of overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, It shows:

> This is not an Azure AD B2C directory. To create a new B2C directory &
> manage your consumer identities in the cloud, click the articles
> below.

Make sure you follow the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#create-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant) to create the B2C tenant.

If you have created it, you need to [switch to the B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant#select-your-b2c-tenant-directory).